# Error, al leer datos enviados desde JS con Fetch en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

Buen día a todos, paso por aquí para pedirles el favor de ayudarme con un problema en mi código que lleva varios días y la verdad no he podido arreglar. Lo que pasa es que estoy intentando leer los datos de un Array enviado desde JS utilizando Fetch API a PHP, lo cual me funcionó a la mitad, dado que la respuesta del Json en el JS es correcta, pero en PHP me sale un error, el cual muestro en las siguientes imágenes, es como si $_POST estuviera vacío, pero lo raro es que la respuesta enviada por el json_encode() y leída en el JS es correcta, no muestra ningún error.

Agradecería enormemente la ayuda de ustedes.

```
    //Archivo JS
    
    const servicios=[1,2,3,4];
    
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    
        e.preventDefault();
    
        getDatos();
    
    });
    
    
    async function getDatos(){

    const datos=new FormData();

    datos.append('s',servicios);

    const url="http://localhost/Curso_HTML/prueba.php";

    const respuesta= await fetch(url,{
        method:"POST",
        body: datos
    });

    const resultado= await respuesta.json();

    console.log(resultado);
}



//Archivo PHP

//<?php

    $respuesta= $_POST['s'];

    echo json_encode($respuesta);
//?>

//HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button>Enviar</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

//imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error que muestras es porque estas queriendo acceder a la URL (eso quiere decir que le pides un GET) y esa URL solo reacciona con POST, es decir con un formulario. Por eso el javascript enviando el FETCH si funciona bien y en cambio abriendo el enlace no funciona.

Comment: Si el PHP te muestra un error y si tu dices que el `$_POST` está vacío, como que sería bueno que pusieres el código de ese PHP...

Comment: buen día amigo, muchas gracias por responder, el código esta arriba después del JS.

Comment: buen día amigos, muchas gracias por responder, en el primer caso, la respuesta de Goyo David, como haría en ese caso?